# In C# how to compare two same dates (with same time stamp)which are in different formats like DD/MM/YYYY and YYYY/DD/MM? Any way without Date format?

Tags: c#

One interviewer asked, how to compare two datetimes with different formats,but both the dates are same and asked me to write a code to check whether both are equal. Is there any possible way to do it with out using inbuilt date time formatter classes ?? Please help. Thanks

I am expecting a solution in easy way. If possible or else any explanation how to solve it .

Comment: If "but both the dates are same" is already assumed, why do you need to compare anything?

Comment: A date should be stored as DateTime (or DateOnly), which does *not* have a format

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Sweeper basically it's an coding interview question for me. I was not able to answer that. So just checking..

Comment: Do you mean that you have that same datetime stored in differently formatted strings?Than you can have a look about `DateTime.ExtractParse` method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0

Comment: Run. Why in the world would you **ever** not use the easiest way to implement something? Interview questions ordered on wish ... *smh

Comment: Of course, knowing which ones have what format, you can split and compare the matching components lexically. It's only for equal or not, right?

Comment: The answer to the interview question is to use the best tool for the job, not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming they are just strings, you can just parse them using `DateTime.ParseExact()`, which would give you two DateTime objects, which can then be compared. Example:

```cs
var date1 = "2023/01/01";
var date2 = "01/01/2023";

var parsedDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "yyyy/MM/dd", new DateTimeFormatInfo());
var parsedDate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date2, "dd/MM/yyyy", new DateTimeFormatInfo());
        
Console.WriteLine(parsedDate1 == parsedDate2); //True
```

If you are unable to use `DateTime.Parse` or similar, something like this is the simplest way I can think of to do what you want:

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var date1 = "2023/01/01";
    var date2 = "01/01/2023";

    var (year1, month1, day1) = SplitDate("yyyy/MM/dd", date1);
    var (year2, month2, day2) = SplitDate("dd/MM/yyyy", date2);

    var datesAreEqual = 
        year1 == year2 && 
        month1 == month2 && 
        day1 == day2;

    Console.WriteLine(datesAreEqual); //True
}

private static (string year, string month, string day) SplitDate(string pattern, string date)
{
    const string yearPattern = "yyyy";
    const string monthPattern = "MM";
    const string dayPattern = "dd";
        
    var yearIndex = pattern.IndexOf(yearPattern, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    var monthIndex = pattern.IndexOf(monthPattern, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    var dayIndex = pattern.IndexOf(dayPattern, StringComparison.Ordinal);

    var year = date.Substring(yearIndex, yearPattern.Length);
    var month = date.Substring(monthIndex, monthPattern.Length);
    var day = date.Substring(dayIndex, dayPattern.Length);

    return (year, month, day);
}
```

Comment: _"with out using inbuilt date time formatter classes"_ - my impression was that this excludes the parse methods explicitly.

Comment: In hindsight I think you might be right, I've added a non-`DateTime` solution too.

Comment: I would use `ReadOnlySpan<char>` to avoid creating new strings but close enough.